# Category in wordpress theme customization / Image slider not coming up

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. I am using [**doctorial**](http://webdevrajan.com/demo/doctorial/) theme for my website. By default it did not have Image Slider on home page as shown in the link. So I am trying to add it through customize option.

I can see slider option in *Homepage Section > Slider Section.* where one can enable slider. One has to select Category for it. There are only 2 options in dropdown, 'Select Category' and 'Uncategorized'

[image]

No matter which option I select, slider is not coming up. Am I missing something?

I have even tried to create new category as per [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/category/).
But not able to create slider.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 2 days. Finally found the answer on following links

- [Link1](https://www.vmthemes.com/how-to-setup-image-slider-on-home-page/)
- [Link2](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/home-slider-not-showing/)

If explanation in Link 2 is not clear

- Go to page where you want to add slider. *Dashboard -> Pages -> (Edit Page)*
- Check the Page attribute section on right corner. Expand section.
- Click Template dropdown.
- Select 'Home Page'
- Update page.

[image]